# sqlite3-ruby . error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite3-ruby

`` rake aborted!
no such file to load -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native
:33:in require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:33:inrescue in require'
:29:in `require' ``

i jus keep gettin this error .
info on my system 
Ubuntu server 10.04 
rails 2.3.8
ruby 1.9.2 
sqlite3-ruby 1.3.2 (even installed libsqlite3-ruby1.9.1)

Any solutions on how to deal with this problem .........

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use a lower version of sqlite3?

do `sudo gem uninstall sqlite3-ruby`and then do a `gem install sqlite3-ruby --version=1.2.5`.